# I want to have user input alter a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, user-input

So I want two input boxes or prompts that have you enter your gamertag, and then another gamertag.
 the base url would be this:
"http://joeydood.com/default.aspx?p1=&p2="

and then when someone enters:
"gamertag1" then "gamertag2" and clicks the button,
 the link changes to:
 http://joeydood.com/default.aspx?p1=gamertag1&p2=gamertag2"
and opens that link automatically

I was trying this

```js
$(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var url = "http://joeydood.com/default.aspx?p1=q";
        url += $('#q').val();
        window.location = url;
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="q" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" />
```

But it is not working , Please help.

Comment: What isn't working exactly? It produces the wrong URL?

Comment: Thats correct, it ends up not producing the proper url and i can't figure out why

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please don't forget to mark it as the "accepted" answer. I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just had an extra "q" character in the URL. To make it a little easier to read, I'd recommend putting the `p1` and `p2` on the same line on which you're adding the gamertag to the URL.

You may also want to read more about [query strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), so in the future you can better understand the structure of them.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var url = "http://joeydood.com/default.aspx";
        url += '?p1='  + $('#q1').val();
        url += '&p2=' + $('#q2').val();
        window.location = url;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

gamertag 1:
<input type="text" id="q1" />

gamertag 2:
<input type="text" id="q2" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" />
```